# 405 Method not allowed with POST + Flask

Tags: python, html, post, flask

I've been finding a 405 error when I try to pass a form by POST to a python script using flask.

My Python is like this:

```
@app.route('/make', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def make():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return "its working"
```

My form is like this:

```
<form method="POST" target="/make">
        <div id="Question">
</form>
```

My code is kinda big so I'm not reproducing it entirely. I cant seem to find my mistake. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't you mean to use `action` instead of `target` ? target will open a new page at /make which is a get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your form you need to use `action` instead of `target`

```
<form method="POST" action="/make">
        <div id="Question">
</form>
```

more details: [form_action](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/att_form_action.asp)